# Find all $0$-$1$ vectors in a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have $m$ $n$-dimensional $0$-$1$ vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m$. My problem is to find *all* other $0$-$1$ vectors in the linear space that is spanned by $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m$.

For example: if $v_1=(0, 1, 1)$, $v_2=(0, 0, 1)$, then there is only one $0$-$1$ vector in the vector space, that is $(0, 1, 0) = v_1 - v_2$.

Can anybody help me with this problem? Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: $(0,0,0)$ is also in the vector space, so you might want to say only "one *non-trivial*..."

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large are $m$ and $n$ in your application?

Comment: @ErickWong you are right, I actually seek the non-trivial vectors. $m$ and $n$ may as large as hundreds. Do you have any idea? thanks  a lot

Comment: If $m = 100$ and $n \ge 100$, then the number of 0-1 vectors can easily be $2^{100}$.  Do you really want to find all of them, or just count them?  Or characterize them in some way? (it's not obvious how to compactly represent them)

Comment: I'm thinking you don't want to choose all combinations of i vectors, 1 <= i <= m, permute over all possibilities of vector addition and subtraction, then check if the resultant vector is some multiple of 0-1 vector? You want an efficient result?

Comment: @KooZhengqun Do you have a clear sense of how to iterate through all possible linear combinations?  One way would be to test all $2^n$ possible vectors for inclusion, but it would be nice to find a method that works for arbitrarily large $n$ and small $m$ (it is known that at most $2^m$ 0-1 vectors can belong to an $m$-dimensional space, regardless of how large $n$ is).

Comment: thanks, testing all $2^n$ possible vectors is too expensive. I want to find a feasible algorithm to get all these vectors , or may be  an approximation algorithm to get $some$ such vectors